# How to generate blog posts from database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post, blogs

How do I make a form, like Wordpress and Drupal, that adds data to the mySQL database?

Then, and this is more important, how do I go about making a PHP file (say, index.php) that loads the appropriate data from the database, formats that data into a post, and displays it without me having to create a file for each post.

I have tried two different ways so far: a list of dummy posts and a mySQL database, but I don't want a list of duplicated .php files in case I want to change the site's format later and I don't know how to apply a template to the raw data in the database and display that. I know how to inject the data in a PHP file but I don't want to have to do that for every post.

It seems like a lot of work but I don't even know how to go about trying it.

EDIT: Sorry, I suppose I wasn't very clear. I know how to work with PHP and mySQL, and I know how to populate a webpage with data from a table etc. What I'm trying to do however is create a template along with some code that will take rows out of a table, apply a format to that data, and display it on the webpage AND do that for multiple posts in order (so that I end up with a page with many posts on it). Of course I could make each individual post, put it in a file, write some PHP to extract data from the db and put it in the right places in the html, apply some css and voila I've got a blog post that I can now `include` in the index.php. But I don't really want to end up with a hundreds files, each of which I have customized by hand. I want to automate this process, and I'm wondering how.

Comment: Try reading some tutorials then come back with your code, explain what failed, and what did you try to solve it.

Comment: Its not actually as hard as you imagine it to be. Its just basic adding to the DB form a form, and then where you want to display, selecting data. Have you done anything like this before?

Comment: All code is a lot of work and most working programmers don't know how to go about solving it on first blush.  So welcome to coding.  Go read some tuts, try something, fail, then improve.  Ask questions here when stumped on something specific.

Comment: This is one of the many tutorials out there. Seems easy enough to follow. http://www.daveismyname.com/tutorials/php-tutorials/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php/

Comment: why not just use wordpress or drupal then?

Comment: Fortunately, all of these projects are open source. You can go read source codes of both wordpress and dupral. There are forums and communities behind them.

Comment: Please see the edit. I don't think I've been very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I sound patronising but the question sounds like you're missing a few key concepts.

php has variables which you can declare like so...

```
$my_variable = "Some text!";
```

Instead of setting the variable manually (usually referred to as hard coding) you could set it with a value from the database (this requires a connection to an SQL database and the creation of an SQL string which you run to retrieve the required data)

```
$my_variable = $database_text;
```

Then, and this is the cool bit, you can "echo" back the text stored in this variable. This results in the php script outputting the text as HTML, like so...

```
echo $my_variable;
```

Put those basic pieces together and you should be able to create one page that will show you any data you require, with the help of some tutorials! This one doesn't look too bad, they use print instead of echo but its almost the same thing... http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php.htm

Comment: Sorry! I do know how to use PHP and mySQL. My fault for not explaining well. Please see the edit for what I'm really trying to do.